# Java - How i can restart ServiceLoader

Tags: java, serviceloader

How can I stop the ServiceLoader so that I can reload the jars?
I have tried to call the load method again. Unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the javadoc documentation you can use the [`reload`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#reload--) method:

> Clear this loader's provider cache so that all providers will be reloaded.
>
> After invoking this method, subsequent invocations of the iterator method will lazily look up and instantiate providers from scratch, just as is done by a newly-created loader.
>
> This method is intended for use in situations in which new providers can be installed into a running Java virtual machine.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that. I tried "reload()", too, but unfortunately it did not work. My test method had output the same debug text.

Comment: Can you post your test method in your question?